# How to stack videos vertically in moviepy?

Tags: python, moviepy

While using moviepy, I use clips_array which stacks clips side by side. How can I make this vertically ?

this is my code

```
from conf import SAMPLE_INPUTS, SAMPLE_OUTPUTS
from moviepy.editor import *

length = 10

clip1 = VideoFileClip('vid1.mp4').subclip(0, 0 + length)
clip2 = VideoFileClip('vid2.mp4').subclip(0, 0 + length)

combined = clips_array([[clip1, clip2]])
combined = combined.resize(height=1920)
combined = combined.crop(x1=1166.6, y1=0, x2=2246.6, y2=1920)
combined.write_videofile('test.mp4')
```

Answer (score 1):

A clips_array is composed of row and columns

In the code you show here, clip1 and clip2 are on the same row and two differents columns. To make them on the same column you can use this code

`combined = clips_array([[clip1], [clip2]])`